# How to open an app with google assistant

Tags: chatbot, actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

I would like my assistant to fire up an app on the phone, is that possible? 
The assistant does it when I ask it to call someone or sometimes it fires up the browser when I ask for something, will I be able to pass the user onto a web page without him needing to click the richCard?

Thanks

Comment: See this question on Deep Linking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174764/google-action-deep-linking

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for.
I already have fulfillment in place, what I want is to open an actual app(not my app) from the assistant. another example is when I ask the assistant to play something in Youtube and it actually opens the app.
I would like to provide the user a link but rather than him having to open it I would like chrome to open right away.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not [possible](https://plus.google.com/u/1/118444150167971910590/posts/hh34mQhwHvu)

Also excited for this feature