# Google action - deep linking

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am implementing app for google assistant . I build simple conversation app with the help of Api.ai tool and it works fine .

Now i want to communicate to my application(Which is installed in android devices) when user trigger particular intent(Created in Api.ai) by saying some text. Guide me to right place to achieve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For that, you need to use the [fulfillment](https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook) option of Api.ai. You will need to have a webserver for that, not just an Android app.

You first will need to enable the webhook in the Fulfillment tab:

[image: Description]

There, you will put an url to your server that performs the action you want. Check the [Actions on Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/) to see how to respond with the correct format to give an answer to your user in the Google Assistant.

Then, you need to go to the particular intent that should trigger your server and enable the Webhook there too:

[image]

Comment: I have setup the things that you are saying but I can't find a way to create the right format response to open my Android app. Could you show me an example?Thanks in advance @Taís Bellini

Comment: This does not answer the question asked 'Now i want to communicate to my application(Which is installed in android devices)'